# Limit for `onErrorContinue(...)` in Flux?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a (possibly infinite) `Flux` source that is supposed to first store each message (e.g. into a database) and then asynchronously forward the messages (e.g. using Spring `WebClient`).

The forward(s) in case of failure are supposed to log an error, without completing the source `Flux`.

I however realized that forward(s) wihtin the flow (`flatMap(...)`) block execution of the source `Flux` after exactly 256 messages that cause exceptions (e.g. `reactor.retry.RetryExhaustedException`).

Representative example that fails in the assert since only 256 messages are processed:

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void sourceBlockAfter256Exceptions() {
    int numberOfRequests = 500;
    Set<Integer> sink = new HashSet<>();
    Flux
            .fromStream(IntStream.range(0, numberOfRequests).boxed())
            .map(sink::add)
            .flatMap(i -> Mono
                    // normally the forwards are contained here e.g. by means of Mono.when(...).thenReturn(...).retryWhen(...):
                    .error(new Exception("any"))
            )
            .onErrorContinue((throwable, o) -> log.error("Error", throwable))
            .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Assertions.assertEquals(numberOfRequests, sink.size());
}
```

Doing the forward within the `subscribe(...)` doesn't block the source `Flux` but that's certainly no solution, since I don't possibly want to lose messages.

Questions:

- What has happened here? (probably related to some state stored in just one bit)
- How can I do this correctly?

**EDIT:**

According to the discussion below I've constructed an example that uses `FluxMessageChannel` (which up to my understanding is made for infinite streams and definitly not expected to block after 256  Errors) and has exactly the same behaviour:

```
@Test
@SneakyThrows
public void maxConnectionWithChannelTest() {
    int numberOfRequests = 500;
    Set<Integer> sink = new HashSet<>();

    FluxMessageChannel fluxMessageChannel = MessageChannels.flux().get();

    fluxMessageChannel.subscribeTo(
            Flux
                    .fromStream(IntStream
                            .range(0, numberOfRequests).boxed()
                            .map(i -> MessageBuilder.withPayload(i).build())
                    )
                    .map(Message::getPayload)
                    .map(sink::add)
                    .flatMap(i -> Mono.error(new Exception("whatever")))
    );

    Flux
            .from(fluxMessageChannel)
            .subscribe();

    Thread.sleep(3000);
    Assert.assertEquals(numberOfRequests, sink.size());
}
```

**EDIT:**

I just raised an issue in the reactor core project: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/2011

Comment: No idea why it's behaving the way it is off the top of my head, but you almost certainly *don't* want to use `onErrorContinue()` - you'd be better using `onErrorResume(e -> Mono.empty())` or similar within the flatMap call instead (you can of course add a log statement to that too.) `onErrorContinue()` is almost always the wrong operator to use in my experience.

Comment: Yeah, I  was quite surprised too. I know about `onErrorResume()`, however never really understood the difference to `onErrorContinue()`. Since I want my source to continue I decided for the latter and initially didn’t even think about testing more then 10 messages. Anyway thanks for the comment, I’ll verify how `onErrorResume()` behaves.

Comment: `onErrorContinue()` is a specialist operator that short circuits various error detection and technically breaks the reactive spec. It affects compatible *upstream* operators, and so it often has some odd behaviour (it could be that it's somehow not causing the flux to request any more elements after the initial set is sent for instance, but I'm guessing.) It's way to "nicely" named IMHO, and not clear enough in the doc that this is a specialist operator - personally I'd say something like `ignoreUpstreamErrorsWhereCompatible` may be a better choice.

Comment: `onErrorResume()` on the other hand is much more "normal", and inline with the reactive spec - it simply takes an error signal and (possibly, if you want) allows that error to be transformed into another publisher (an empty one if need be.)

Comment: The thing is `.onErrorResume(throwable ->  Flux.empty())` completes the `Flux` immediately. I just had a look into springs `FluxMessageChannel` where `subscribeOn()` apparently does the same as I do in my question. I wonder if the behaviour is the same there.

Comment: It will complete it immediately if you add it as an operator to the `Flux`, since it will resume with the empty publisher you're defining - you need to add it to the *inner flatmap call* - so it becomes something like `Mono.when(...).thenReturn(...).retryWhen(...).onErrorResume(t->Mono.empty())`.

Comment: Ok this for sure works, but doesn't add global behaviour to the `Flux`. Thus any other error can complete the source. Feels pretty unsafe to me.

Comment: `onErrorContinue` doesn't really guarantee to add global behaviour to the `Flux` either (even ignoring the problem here) as it's only compatible with certain operators - and it can swallow exceptions that you then wouldn't plan on it swallowing. It's not really as robust as it might first seem, hence one of the reasons why I generally stay away from it. Besides the point though, since I don't see why it's not working here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insides on this operator. We will accordingly try to work around it for now. I however raised an issue on GitHub (see the edit), since the actual behavior is really dangerous.